# Slow download of static file in .net 6

Tags: asp.net-core, web-deployment, .net-6.0, iis-8, kestrel-http-server

I have a web application build in .net 6 and hosted on IIS. When I download static files which reside in www root folder then download was fast but when I kept same file in other location then there is a massive performance degradation (approx 35%) in downloading.

```
 app.UseStaticFiles();//Static file middleware for wwwroot folder.
 app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions 
        {
            
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider("PhysicalPathOfTheFolder"),
            RequestPath = "/MyPath",                  

        });
  app.UseRouting();
  app.UseAuthorization();
```

As in the above code I am using authorization middleware after the static file location configuration so there will not be any authorization overhead which degrading the performance(Correct me if I am wrong).

My question is Why there is a performance degradation ?

Note: I am downloading the file using fetch api in javascript.
The mime type of file which I am downloading is "application/octet-stream".

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Does that other location is on the same server? You could try to check whether Firewall, Anti-Virus or anything else on your network taking time and make the download slow. You could try to check the Network Monitor logs. Is it necessary for you to store the file outside WWWroot folder?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes the  other location is on same server infact on same drive. I had also checked other factors like antivirus, firewall but doesn't observed any unusual. Network monitor, IIS log and fidler logs is also normal.

Comment: You could try to check the Network tab of the developer tools in the browser. Try to see when file is getting downloaded, what is consuming the time. If it shows some information then we could try to look into that thing that may help you narrow down the issue. Further, in the Fiddler traces, you could check the same.